# OSMdroid default startlocation when no GPS

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, osmdroid

I am making an App that makes use of and OSMdroid map. 
I want the center of the map to be where the location of the user is. This works so far when GPS is on, but I also want to assure a default center in case the GPS does not work/is off. I tested my code by switching off the GPS on my device. Her is the code I tried by myself,  but the center of the map is being placed in the middle of the ocean if GPS is off.

```
    myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, osmv);
    myLocationoverlay.enableMyLocation(); 
    myLocationoverlay.disableCompass();
    myLocationoverlay.enableFollowLocation();
    myLocationoverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
    myLocationoverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    if (myLocationoverlay.getMyLocation() != null){ 
            // go to MyLocation
            osmv.getController().animateTo(myLocationoverlay
                    .getMyLocation());
        }
        else {
        }
        //go to NYcenter
        osmv.getController().animateTo(new GeoPoint(40714200, 74006400));   


        }
```

What is the correct way to set a default start location?

Comment: what about `osmv.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(40714200, 74006400));`

Comment: I have tried this first but also got set into the ocean and not to NYC

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine but your coordinates are wrong. Try replacing `osmv.getController().animateTo(new GeoPoint(40714200, 74006400));`  with `osmv.getController().animateTo(new GeoPoint(40714200, -74006400));`